# How can I use the ionic-barcode scanner to scan the pdf417 barcode on the driver licenses and retrive information?

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic4, ionic5

This is the JSON that is retrieved from the barcode.

{"text":"03451736","format":"UPC_E","cancelled":"false"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN App main Module add imports of barcode scanner

```
import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
```

Add it to the providers array

```
providers: [
    .....
    ;;;;; Other providers
    ;;;;;
    BarcodeScanner,

  ],
```

And in component

```
import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
```

Initialize in constructor

```
constructor(public barcodeCtrl: BarcodeScanner)
```

Provide scan options

```
const options: BarcodeScannerOptions = {
      preferFrontCamera: false,
      showFlipCameraButton: false,
      showTorchButton: true,
      torchOn: false,
      prompt: 'Place a barcode inside the scan area',
      resultDisplayDuration: 500,
      formats: 'QR_CODE,DATA_MATRIX,UPC_A,UPC_E,EAN_8,EAN_13,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,ITF,PDF_417,AZTEC',
      orientation: 'portrait',
      disableAnimations: true, // iOS
      disableSuccessBeep: false, // iOS and Android
    };
```

On button Click call below function

```
Scan(){

 this.barcodeCtrl.scan(options).then((barcodeData) => {
        console.log('Barcode data', barcodeData);
        this.licenceData = JSON.parse(barcodeData.text);  // This will contain your licence details 


        
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      });

}
```